# How to manage SSIS Maintenance Plans DTSX files with powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, xml-namespaces

my purpose is to script in powershell SQL Server maintenance plans creation/modifications using templates. These templates are maintenance plans extracted to .dtsx files using dtutil.

A maintenance plan contains several tasks.

I want to be able to add a new database for each task in my dtsx file, in order to import it (replacing the old one in SQL server).

a sample of my dtsx file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="6/26/2015 11:24:25 AM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  .....
  <DTS:Executables>
    <DTS:Executable
      DTS:refId="Package\All"
      DTS:CreationName="STOCK:SEQUENCE"
      DTS:Description="Subplan_1"
      DTS:Disabled="True"
      .....
      <DTS:Executables>
        <DTS:Executable
          DTS:refId="Package\All\Back Up Database Task"
          DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.DbMaintenanceBackupTask"
          DTS:Description="Back Up Database Task"
          DTS:DTSID="{04209de7-5ea4-4e5c-843e-451db1393625}"
          DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.DbMaintenanceBackupTask"
          DTS:LocaleID="-1"
          DTS:ObjectName="Back Up Database Task"
          DTS:TaskContact="Back Up Database Task; Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server v9; © 2004 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1"
          DTS:ThreadHint="0">
          .....
          <DTS:ObjectData>
            <SQLTask:SqlTaskData
              SQLTask:Connection="{6CAC94AA-3395-44B3-A935-D14FC08186DF}"
              SQLTask:DatabaseSelectionType="4"
              SQLTask:ServerVersion="12"
              SQLTask:ExtendedLogging="False"
              SQLTask:LocalConnectionForLogging="Local server connection"
              SQLTask:TaskName=""
              SQLTask:IgnoreDatabasesInNotOnlineState="False"
              SQLTask:BackupAction="0"
              .....
              SQLTask:BackupEncryptorName="" xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask">
              <SQLTask:SelectedDatabases
                SQLTask:DatabaseName="db1" />
            </SQLTask:SqlTaskData>
          </DTS:ObjectData>
        </DTS:Executable>
        <DTS:Executable
          DTS:refId="Package\All\Check Database Integrity Task"
          DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.DbMaintenanceCheckIntegrityTask"
          .....
        ....
    ........
```

So I'm trying to add a new item in the SQLTask:SqlTaskData section

```
              <SQLTask:SelectedDatabases
                SQLTask:DatabaseName="db2" />
            </SQLTask:SqlTaskData>
```

and this, using the tip here http://www.pawlowski.cz/2012/06/manipulating-ssis-packages-powershell/ which looks like very fine.

But in this tip the namespace is uniq : DTS.

In my file, we have 2 namespaces : DTS and SQLTask.

Before trying to add the new section, I just want to read it. Here is my code

```
#Get List of all relevat SSIS Packages
$file = Get-ChildItem "F:\maint_plan2014\modified\MaintenancePlan db.dtsx"

#get the content of SSIS package as XML
$dts = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)

#create XmlNamespaceManager
$mng = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]($dts.NameTable)
#add a DTS namespace to the XmlNamespaceManager
$mng.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")
#add a SQLTask namespace to the XmlNamespaceManager
$mng.AddNamespace("SQLTask", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts/Tasks/SQLTask")

#use XPath query to get all tasks
$tasks = $dts.SelectSingleNode("/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable", $mng)
```

until here, all is ok, $tasks contains all my tasks

Now, I try to query the task :

```
PS P:\> $dts.SelectSingleNode("/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable[1]/DTS:ObjectData", $mng)

SqlTaskData
-----------
SqlTaskData

PS P:\>
```

But when I want to go further, in the namespace SQLTask, the result is empty :

```
PS P:\> $dts.SelectSingleNode("/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable[1]/DTS:ObjectData/SQLTask:SqlTaskData", $mng)
PS P:\>
```

when I query like that (see below), it works fine, but in order to add a new database, I mean I have to work with namespaces, isn't it ?

```
PS P:\> $dts.SelectSingleNode("/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable[1]/DTS:ObjectData", $mng).SqlTaskData


Connection                      : {6CAC94AA-3395-44B3-A935-D14FC08186DF}
DatabaseSelectionType           : 4
ServerVersion                   : 12
ExtendedLogging                 : False
LocalConnectionForLogging       : Local server connection
TaskName                        :
IgnoreDatabasesInNotOnlineState : False
BackupAction                    : 0
BackupIsIncremental             : False
BackupFileGroupsFiles           :
BackupDeviceType                : 2
BackupPhysicalDestinationType   : 2
BackupDestinationType           : 0
BackupDestinationAutoFolderPath : C:\ClusterStorage\Backup\MSSQL12.INSTDB\MSSQL\Backup
BackupActionForExistingBackups  : 0
BackupCreateSubFolder           : True
BackupFileExtension             :
BackupVerifyIntegrity           : True
ExpireDate                      : 2015-07-10T00:00:00
RetainDays                      : 14
InDays                          : True
UseExpiration                   : False
BackupCompressionAction         : 0
CopyOnlyBackup                  : False
IgnoreReplicaType               : False
CredentialName                  :
ContainerName                   :
UrlPrefix                       :
IsBackupEncrypted               : False
BackupEncryptionAlgorithm       : 0
BackupEncryptorType             : 0
BackupEncryptorName             :
SQLTask                         : www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask
SelectedDatabases               : SelectedDatabases



PS P:\> $dts.SelectSingleNode("/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable[1]/DTS:ObjectData", $mng).SqlTaskData.SelectedDatabases

DatabaseName
------------
db1


PS P:\>
```

Could anybody help me ? maybe I misunderstood something managing xml file and namespaces ...